# why tensorflow TFLiteConverter.from_session require the same size for input and output

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use TFLiteConverter to convert my network. So I tried the sample code first. It works. But after some modification, it sends back error. Seems the input_array and output_array must be the same size. I just don't understand why. Can anybody help me?

I modified the size of img from and the size of var from [1,64,64,3 to [1,64,3,1]
the complete code is pasted bellow`enter code here`

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(name="img", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 64, 1))
var = tf.get_variable("weights", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 3, 1))
val = tf.matmul(img,var)
out = tf.identity(val, name="out")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(val.shape)
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [img], [out])
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

The ERROR message:
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1 and 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'BatchMatMulV2') with input shapes: [1,64,64,1], [1,64,3,1].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the TFLite conversion, but with build the graph in the first place.

`tf.matmul` operates on the inner-most 2D matrices in your tensors. So in your case, you are trying to matrix multiply a matrix of shape `64x1` by a matrix of size `3x1`, which is not valid. Matrix multiplication requires that columns of the first operand is equal to the rows in the second operand, but here `1 != 3` so it doesn't work.

For example, replace the `3` by a `1` then it will work :

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(name="img", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 64, 1))
var = tf.get_variable("weights", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 3, 1))
val = tf.matmul(img,var)
out = tf.identity(val, name="out")
```